# how to generate allure test report in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium-webdriver, allure, selenide

I created some automation scripts using "selenide", "testng", "maven", "eclipse".
I tried to add allure test results. I followed allure-testng-maven instructions and updated pom.xml.

For running test from eclipse I'm doing rightclick on pom.xml + "run as" + " Maven test". This is executing all the testng tests and generated allure xml files in "./target/allure-results" folder.

My doubt is how to see the allure report from eclipse.

Below is my pom.xml file.

```
 <!-- language: lang-xml -->

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</groupId>
<artifactId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>servicenow</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<allure.version>1.5.0.RC2</allure.version>
<aspectj.version>1.8.9</aspectj.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


<dependency>
 <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
 <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
 <version>2.53.1</version>
 <scope>test</scope>            
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
 <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
 <version>2.53.1</version>
 <scope>test</scope>            
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
 <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
 <version>2.53.1</version>
 <scope>test</scope>            
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
 <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
 <version>2.53.1</version>
 <scope>test</scope>    
</dependency>  
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
 <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
 <version>2.53.1</version>
 <scope>test</scope>    
</dependency>

<dependency>                
 <groupId>org.testng</groupId>                              
 <artifactId>testng</artifactId>                                
 <version>6.9.10</version>                              
 <scope>test</scope>                                        
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
 <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
 <version>3.9.1</version>
 <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
 <artifactId>allure-testng-adaptor</artifactId>
 <version>${allure.version}</version>
 <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
       <groupId>junit</groupId>
       <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
 </exclusions>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
    <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                </argLine>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        <!--Needed only to show reports locally. Run jetty:run and
        open localhost:8080 to show the report-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.0.M1</version>
            <configuration>
                    <webAppSourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site/allure-maven-plugin</webAppSourceDirectory>
                <stopKey>stop</stopKey>
                <stopPort>1234</stopPort>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<reporting>
    <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>

</project>
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run maven goal 'site' to generate a report. Just right click on your project -> Run as -> Maven build... And then type 'site' as goal and run. Alternatively you can type the goals 'clean test site', which exectutes all tests and then generates the report in one maven run. The report should be located under target/site by default.

Comment: Sorry for accepting it late.
It worked for me.
Thaks!